# Type 'LoadableComponent<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I'm trying for migration react-router-dom v5 to v6.

```
// react-router-dom v5
<Route exact path="/" component={router.Home} />

// react-router-dom v6
<Route path="/*" element={router.Home} /> // error
```

and got this error

`Type 'LoadableComponent<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'. Type 'ComponentClass<ExtraComponentProps, any> & LoadableComponentMethods<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.`

How can i fix it ?

here is my code sample

routes.ts

```
import loadable from '@loadable/component';

export const Home = loadable(() => import('./pages/Home'));
```

App.tsx

```
import * as router from 'src/routes';

<Route path="/*" element={router.Home} /> // error
```

package.json

```
//devDependency
"@types/react": "^18.0.26",
"@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
"@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
"@types/loadable__component": "^5.13.4",

//dependency
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.6.2",
"@loadable/component": "^5.15.2",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<Route path="/*" element={router.Home} /> // error
```

Use

```html
const {Home} = router;
...
<Route path="/*" element={<Home />} />
```

Comment: If i have many component (e.g. Home, Login, Signup, Mypage, Notice ...), then i have to write them all like this?

`const {Home, Login, Signup ...} = router;

<Route path="/*" element={<Home />} />
<Route path="/login/* element={<Login />} />`

it seems inefficient..

Comment: You are correct...

Comment: is there any other way?

because i have so many components and pages..

Comment: 'Home' cannot be used as a JSX component.

Type 'import("/Users/.../node_modules/@types/loadable__component/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'React.ReactNode'.

Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.

Comment: And i got this error

Comment: as the initial error states, the `element` property is expecting a value of type `ReactNode` but the actual value is of `LoadableComponent<unknown>` (because of lazy loaded component).
The answer should work. 
Please checkout https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-loadable-component-8w4ht?file=/src/App.js:174-179

Comment: Thx! i solved this error like this ```<Route path="/*" element={<router.Home />} />```